# What do you call the output of a truth table?

Tags: logic, terminology, definitions

I know that the value of said output can be either True of False, but what is the actual output called?

Another way of phrasing the question is, is what do you call the resolution of a complex proposition?

Comment: A line in a truth-table correspons to a *valuation*, i.e. to a "truth-assignment" of (truth) values to the elementary proposition occurring in the "complex" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the truth value of the sentence/formula.

And the truth values of the atomic propositions are referred to as truth assignments.

i.e.

" α = (A → B) V (B → A)

α is a tautology because its *truth value* is T regardless of the *truth assignments* to propositions A and B."

Comment: I know, but what if you wanted to just talk about complex propositions regardless of the truth value of said complex proposition when the propositions that form it are in any given state?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're saying, sorry. Let me try this: you can talk about the truth value - without specifying if it is T or F - of a formula regardless of the truth assignments of its atomic propositions.

Comment: Check what I added to the answer - is this the situation you're referring to?